# gray bulk between toolbar and scrollview

Tags: swiftui

Instead of using default toolbar I have created a custom toolbar. The problem I am having with the custom toolbar is between the toolbar and the scrollview there is an empty bulk that I could not figure out where the heck it comes from.

[image]

The code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedSelection: TabSelection = .market
    
    init() {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.first)]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.first)]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedSelection) {
                MarketView()
                    .tag(TabSelection.market)
                InterestView()
                    .tag(TabSelection.interest)
                WalletView()
                    .tag(TabSelection.wallet)
            }.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
            Spacer()
            TabBarView(selectedSelection: $selectedSelection)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have changed the code to:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        TabView(selection: $selectedSelection) {
            MarketView()
                .tag(TabSelection.market)
            InterestView()
                .tag(TabSelection.interest)
            WalletView()
                .tag(TabSelection.wallet)
        }.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
            .border(.blue)
        TabBarView(selectedSelection: $selectedSelection)
    }
}
```

However, the gray bulk does not disappears

[image]

Search view looks as follows:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @State private var searchInterest: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject private var interestAggr: InterestAggr
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(interestAggr.interests.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            InterestSelectionItem(model: $interestAggr.interests[index])
                            Divider()
                        }.padding(.vertical, 5)
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }.navigationTitle("search")
                .searchable(text: $searchInterest, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "enter your interest")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add .ignoresSafeArea() view modifier to the tabs?

Comment: Firstly remove the spacer below the TabView as that will always add space in that context in my experience. Also set spacing between the items in the VStack to zero with VStack(spacing: 0). I would also try putting a border around the TabView as they always have some padding and this will show it - .border(.blue)

Comment: OK. That does make things clearer as to what view has what bounds. With the blue border it is clear that the Tab View has the extra "grey space" in it. For clarity can you update the question with just the latest iteration of the code which is clearer. ie. remove the previous code and pics. For debugging I would reduce the SearchView as simple as possible. Just try a simple List. Navigation View has a lout of layout preconfigured. Maybe put some border around the components in the SearchView - a great debug mechanism when it comes to strange spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your outer `VStack` which wraps the `TabView` and custom tab view to a `ZStack(alignment: .bottom)`.

Also, is the SearchView navigated to from InterestView? If so, you don't need another `NavigationStack` in SearchView.